# How can I save audio wav file without data clipping?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, normalization, wav

I am using MATLAB tool for extracting silence part from audio WAV files. After extracting silence part from audio, I want to save new audio as a WAV file.
For this process, I use 'audiowrite' function. However, the program warns to me with this message :

> Warning: Data clipped when writing file.

I tried to add 'BitsPerSample' value with single file format(32 bit) and I dont take a message from program with this way. I saved audio files with 32 bit but WAV files should be 16 bit.

How can I fix this problem?

```
audiowrite(filename,y,fs,'BitsPerSample',32);
```

Note: I also normalized data and problem is same.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**

I want to normalize audio samples as mean 0 and standard deviation or variance 1.Thus, I use z-score normalization technique.
 Also,`y/max(abs(y))` method is normalized data between -1 and 1. However, mean and variance are not equal to 0 and 1 respectively. These techniques are normalized data with different way.

Actually, My question is that How can I save samples with z score normalization technique without data clipping?

Comment: Please share the code you use for the z-normalization. Probably you exceed 1 or -1 and therefore the data gets clipped. have you tried to add `native` to your audioread command?

Comment: I know exceed range between -1 and 1. z normalization code is y1=(y -mean(y))/(std(y)) or zscore(y). If I normalize the data again after z normalization, data converts to orjinal. Therefore, z normalization is unnecessary to use. No, I haven't. However, 'native' parameter converts double to integer.

Comment: The reason you get the message, and the reason your data gets clipped is that it exceeds 1 and/or -1. If you do not want that, add this line `y1 = y1/max(abs(y1))` and the maximum will not exceed 1 nor -1.

Comment: Thank you ! It is working very well. Although z-normalization is normalized values between -1 and +1 in default settings, it doesnot work in this process.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's [`audiowrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html) uses different normalizations for different data types. So if you want to get 16bit audio wav file, you should normalize your data to the `[-32768,32767]` range and convert your data to `int16` type:

```
y_normalized = intmax('int16') * y/(max(abs(y))*1.001);
audiowrite(filename, int16(y_normalized), fs)
```

Similarly, for float you should normalize your data to the `[-1,+1]` range :

```
y_normalized = y/(max(abs(y)));
audiowrite(filename, y_normalized, fs)
```

Comment: firstly, thank you for your answering. my data is like : -0,280750148350963 -0,454680031418586, 1,42956036848067, -0,295244305273265 -1,48859655854279. these aren't interger type so your code doesn't work.  I do z-normalization to data as mean 0 and variance 1.  After this process, I want to save it.